# Need to convert sku array into title array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning JavaScript and jQuery and for the project we have to create an online shop. I have created the products and the shopping cart but for now when I open my cart all I can see is the sku and category but I need to convert this to other product variables like image, price. My code so far is the following:

```
var products = {
tricouri: [
{
title: "Tricou athletic cu imprimeu",
sizes: ["M", "L", "XL"],
imageSource: "assets/img/tricou1.jpg",
price: 109.99,
sku: 1
},
{
title: "Tricou slim fit de bumbac organic",
sizes: ["M", "L", "XL"],
imageSource: "assets/img/tricou2.jpg",
price: 200,
sku: 2
}]
}

var cart = [];

function drawCartProducts(cart){
var cartProductsElement = document.getElementById("cart-products");
cartProductsElement.innerHTML = "";

for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.className = "cart-item";
li.innerText = cart[i].sku + " din categoria " + cart[i].categoryId;

cartProductsElement.appendChild(li);

}
}
$(".categ a").click(function() {
currentCategory = $(this).attr("cat-id");
console.log("CATEGORIA CURENTA: ", currentCategory);
drawProducts(currentCategory);
prepareAddToCart();
});

function prepareAddToCart(){
$('.add-to-cart').click(function(){
var product = {
sku: $(this).attr("sku"),
categoryId: $(this).attr("category-id")
}
cart.push(product);
alert("Produsul dumneavoastra a fost adaugat in cos!");
console.log("Cosul: ", cart);
})
}

prepareAddToCart();

var cartState = false;
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you with actual execution of drawCartProducts and show expected output

Comment: Hi, I have updated the snippet and also the project can be seen [here](http://shopposite.ro/Aspire/shop/)

Comment: I strongly recommend to EITHER use dom access and createelement OR jQuery- also a [mcve] with actual jQuery loaded will be testable. Your external JavaScript is not